# About the VB P-CODE mode reverse-engineer

Tags: binary-analysis, visual-basic

I have to reverse-engineer a VB P-CODE mode program. I had the program's P-CODE, but I don't know what it means. For example:

```
Proc: 421840
421100: 04 FLdRfVar                local_0098
421103: 04 FLdRfVar                local_0094
421106: 05 ImpAdLdRf:              435aec
421109: 24 NewIfNullPr             408868
42110C: 0d VCallHresult            CVBApplication::get_
```

I have to find the tools to reverse a program.I want to know what the P-CODE means.Thanks

Comment: google first hit says p-code means packed-code  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_P-Code supposed to be executed by a visual basic virtual machine (msvbvmXXX.dll abandoned after vb6 in favour of clr and .net and a hunch search yields several decompiers for that code like p32dasm , vb-decompiler etc

Answer (score 4):

Here are the two best free and available resources about Microsoft's VB P-Code.
First one, the list of opcodes ([here](http://web.archive.org/web/20101127044116/http://vb-decompiler.com/pcode/opcodes.php?t=1)). Second one, a 12 pages document written by *Alex Ionescu* on how to decompile and analyze VB binaries ([here](http://web.archive.org/web/20071020232030/http://www.alex-ionescu.com/vb.pdf)).

Answer (score 2):

[VB Decompiler Pro](https://www.vb-decompiler.org/products.htm) decompiles VB P-Code to Visual Basic code. See below for an example of the decompilation output:

[image: Decompilation]

Alternatively, if you're looking for help in analyzing the raw P-Code itself, you can check out the following links in addition to the links that [yaspr](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/users/4437/yaspr) [posted](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/8745/1562):

- [VB P-code Information by Mr Silver](http://www.woodmann.com/crackz/Tutorials/Vbpcode.htm)
- [Info about P-code](http://www.woodmann.com/crackz/Archives/Vbpcode.zip)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Alex Ionescu paper, there's also a useful 27-page paper, [VISUAL BASIC REVERSED - A decompiling approach](http://www.reteam.org/papers/e46.pdf) by Andrea Geddon.